# Number of pairs with product less than a given number.

Tags: number-theory

How can we find out the number of positive integer pairs with product less than a specific value. Can someone help me with this.

Comment: This seems awfully similar to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/740454). However, it seems that that question has been put on hold.

Answer (score 0):

I know one way. Let $a$ and $b$ be two positive numbers. Now let $max(a,b)=b$ so $ab<b^2$. Let $b^2=c$. Now $ab<c$.

Suppose we got a positive number $A$ and we wish two find two positive numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$ s.t. $\alpha \beta < A$. Then from the first paragraph it is clear that  <strike>the</strike> **one sufficient but not necessary** condition is that 
max($\alpha$,$\beta$)<$\sqrt{A}$.

Let me again clarify that max($\alpha$,$\beta$)<$\sqrt{A}$ is **not** a necessary condition, but it is a sufficient condition.

Comment: This is not correct. Let $A=16$. You say that $\max{\alpha,\beta}<\sqrt{A}$. However, what about $\alpha=2$, $\beta=8$? $8>\sqrt{16}$.

Comment: Hi @abalter , thankyou for pointing out the mistake. I've clarified it. If it is ok now then tell me.

Comment: Hi @user31782, yes, good correction.